# Overflow hidden and position absolute menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow, submenu

I know these problems have been faced by many others and there are solutions available. But none problems I found were similar to me, all had missed `position:relative` for the parent. But I have used `position: relative` and `overflow:hidden` for the parent, and `position: absolute` for children, but the overflow hidden of the parent is hiding the submenu in my menu.

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/837/)

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="menu.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-container">
    <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='drop'>S</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>M</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>P</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>C</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class='drop'>L</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

menu.css

```
#menu-container{
    margin: 60px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* Background color and gradients */
    background-color: white;/*
    background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background-color: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));
    /* Borders */
    border: 1px solid #002232;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    padding: 0;
    z-index:20;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu{
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* Rounded Corners */
    color: #2a6496;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right:30px;
    border:none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

#menu li:hover {
    /* Background color and gradients */
    /*
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #e1e1e1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #e1e1e1);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#e1e1e1));
    */
    background: #428bca;
    /* Rounded corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #2a6496;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:21px;
    background:url("../../images/drop.png") no-repeat right 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li ul{
    margin:4px auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    /*padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;*/
    padding: 0;
    border:1px solid #428bca;
    border-top:none;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
    /* Gradient background */
    background:white;
    /*background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));

    overflow-x: hidden;
    */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li ul li{
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
#menu li ul li:hover{
    background: #13967e;
}
#menu li ul a{
    color: #2a6496;
}

#menu li ul li:hover a{
    color: white;
}
#menu li .input, #menu li .input:hover{
    background: white;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    left: -1px;
    top:auto;
}
```

Removing overflow hidden from menu-container shows the submenu but then the menu-container doesnt contain the menu.

Can someone please help me find what I am doing wrong, so that the submenu too shows up. Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove overflow:hidden from li and #menu-container. Add to #menu-container this code

```
#menu-container:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltfx7/